# What Algorithm Does Mathematica use to Calculate Betweenness Centrality for Unweighted Graphs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, implementation-details

I recently asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888369/betweenness-centrality-how-long-does-mathematica-take) on the Mathematics SE.

Does anyone know, as a follow up, what algorithm *Mathematica* uses to calculate the betweenness centrality vector (of $N$ elements) for an unweighted graph?

Comment: Did you ask Wolfram Support about this?  In my experience they tend to provide the references.

Comment: I have not asked

Comment: Ask them then, and if you get a response, please come back and write an answer to the question.